# How to getSubimage of JPanel?

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, bufferedimage

BufferedImage has a getSubimage(x, y, width, height) method that returns an Image. I am drawing graphics on a JPanel, how would I do something similar to the BufferedImage method with a JPanel?

For example (if only it was correct):

```
BufferedImage bi = jPanel.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render probably any swing component to a buffered image.

Since you just need a sub-image I guess that would make a 2 step process, 1) render your JPanel to a BufferedImage, 2) Get subimage of that.

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(jPanel.getWidth(), jPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)bi.getGraphics();
panel.printAll(g); //I assume you wanted child elements too... otherwise just use paint(g)
BufferedImage result= bi.getSubimage(...);
```

Note: this will only work after all components are initialized, positioned, etc. and displayed.